# HTML5 Canvas Text Resize, Rotate and Change Color

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to resize and  Rotate text in canvas in a similar way to this:

http://simonsarris.com/project/canvasdemo/demo2.html

But I also want to add the rotate and change color functionality.
How would I best implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use all these feature then I would suggest you using either of these javascript libraries to accomplish this

- [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/)
- [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/)
- [GuryJS](http://guryjs.org/)

I've worked with all of them. As always, nothing will probably fit your needs but I would suggest looking into those to get a better view on what you can actually do with the HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Actually this is first time i am working on these type of application ...so what u suggest create this using jquery rather than html5 canvas

Comment: well most of those libraries use the html5 canvas. Its just easier to use them instead of limiting yourself to the code that you have available at the moment on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a good tutorial about Canvas I would say. Something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Canvas_tutorial is a good resource.